BLDC ESC Design choices
I need advises on ESC schema.
I am trying to make a homemade ESC for a 350 W, 36 V BLDC motor.
I am using an Arduino UNO and a 30 V, 5 A supply voltage.
I've already tested a prototype using the following schema:

However, with this setup, the P-channel MOSFETs heat up enormously (RDS(on) is too high I guess) and the motor rotation is a little jerky (probably because some components are incorrectly dimensioned).
Before I start moving on, I'd like your advises on the choice of design.

Should I go with “High and low side driver” to use N-MOSFETs both in high and low side?
Is there some extra-protection that should be added to the previous schema to make it more reliable? I am wondering if I should put some capacitors somewhere near the MOSFETs gates to “smooth” phases transitions.
Are there some thing I did wrong?

Electronic newbie here, there might be mistakes :smile:
Thanks for your time.

Missing decoupling capacitors. Measure Vgs and Vds simultaneously on your oscilloscope and report back.

The supply voltage operating range of TC4427 is 4.5V to 18V. The used 30 V supply will destroy them and the Vgs voltage of IRF5305 also is limited to 20 V.

Put a serial resistor on each gate, 10R or so. You may need them later.

Your P-channel MOSFETs have 60mΩ of ON resistance (RdsON), which means a voltage drop of 0.3V at 5A, and 1.5W of heat generated.
The lower MOSFETs have 17.5mΩ, or about 3.5 times lower resistance and that much less heat generated (about 0.4W), so they will be significantly cooler.
P-channel MOSFETS in general have higher ON resistance than the N-channel models, and they typically cost more at the same time.
But your biggest problem is using the wrong driver for the MOSFETs.
What you have is a DUAL MOSFET driver, which is used when both MOSFET source pins are at the same ground or potential, as in a push-pull converter.
What you need is a HALF-BRIDGE MOSFET driver, which is meant to drive a "totem pole" of two N-channel MOSFETs, that is, having one at the bottom with its source pin at ground level while the other one is at the top with its source pin connected to the lower MOSFETs drain pin.
DUAL drivers typically have low operating voltages not exceeding maximum Vgs, because they only need enough to drive MOSFET gates directly from the supply voltage.
HALF-BRIDGE drivers can typically withstand and drive MOSFETs with voltages much higher than the supply voltage, often going as high as 500v or 600V or even more, and they have provisioning for those higher voltages and the floating midpoint, unlike the ones you are currently using.
I could recommend a specific model number for you, currently I can mention the old IR2104, but you can get more powerful and faster half-bridge drivers for the same or lower price nowadays.

Well, I was working on it .I want to develop a ESC for my pen plotter and some of my projects.
1.Do not go to PMOSFET ,use N-channel.it has low RDS on and high voltage rating ,low  threshold and current rating is high. although you can get many references.
2.coming from drivers it is a good choice. but you want configure the drivers correctly.
apart from this, the switching of high side requires bootstrap circuit it is a major constraint if you have to develop your own ESC board.
Thank you.
